# Strapi Plugin localization

Tags: plugins, localization, strapi

I need help figuring this out

```
debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2022-09-22 11:30:06.580] error: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined
    at Object.addCreateLocalizationAction
```

An error comes up when i add localization option for my strapi plugin  and this is the content scheme, i installed the i18n but it still didnt work

```
module.exports = {
  kind: "collectionType",
  collectionName: "tests",
  info: {
    singularName: "test",
    pluralName: "tests",
    displayName: "test"
  },
  options: {
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      localized :true
    }
  },
  attributes: {
    name: {
      pluginOptions: {
        i18n: {
          localized: true
        }
      },
      type: "string",
      required: true
    },
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to overide the method "**addCreateLocalizationAction**" in i18 localization plugin method with the below code.

```
const addCreateLocalizationAction = (contentType) => {
  const { modelName, apiName } = contentType;

  if(apiName){
    const localizationRoute = createLocalizationRoute(contentType);
    
    strapi.api[apiName].routes[modelName].routes.push(localizationRoute);
    
    strapi.container.get('controllers').extend(`api::${apiName}.${modelName}`, (controller) => {
      return Object.assign(controller, {
        createLocalization: createLocalizationHandler(contentType),
      });
    });
  }
};
```

You can do this step in the strapi registration phase also.